# RDLC Getting specific records in my DataSet

Tags: sql, rdlc

I know that I can use something like:

```
=First(Fields!Group.Value, "helloWorldReport")
=Last(Fields!Group.Value, "helloWorldReport")
```

To get the first and last records of my dataset. However, how can I get the ones in between them? What if I have 9 or 10 other records, can I programmaticaly access to a specific record, i.e. record number 7?

Comment: There is no default function for this, it's quite useless anyway. The number of rows can vary so there is no guarantee it will give a valid value. The entire purpose of using datasources is to dynamically fill the report. If you want to get a specific value you should reference an ID inside the datasource and not the row number. If you really wish to get this function you could write your own using the running row number but ultimately you're probably using a wrong design pattern and probably want to rethink the used model.

Comment: I actually have the model done correctly. Where I have a GroupID connected with a GroupName. My question here is, how do I display the GroupName string based on the GrouID int? Something like this: GroupName = GroupID and then display group name. Any suggetions? Thanks.

Comment: You could use filters but ultimately I suspect you're better off using parameters. If you plan on hardocding the ID values you already aren't dynamically filling anyway....

Comment: Regarding GroupName and GroupId it seems that in VS2015 you can use a new set of functions: Lookup, LookupSet and MultiLookup.

Comment: Sorry for the delay guys. Thanks @tezzo, that worked. However, it only displays if it has records associated with that column, any way to show it regardless if it has or not?